# Chart.JS doen't show anything with Angular.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, charts

I am trying to show graph having same data on Angular JS to HTML. How can I pass my graph to HTML

dashboard.js

```
angular.module('inspinia').controller('dashboardController',['$rootScope','$scope', '$http', function($rootScope, $scope, $http) {
var labels = [];
var Data = [];
var piedata = [];
var completed = 0;
var len=0;
var data = dashboardFactory.getData().success(function(resp){

len = resp.length;
for(var i = 0;i<len;i++)
{
labels.push(resp[i].address);
Data.push(resp[i].value);
piedata.push({"label" :resp[i].address, "value" :resp[i].value })
completed++;
graphload();    
}
});
function graphload()
{
if(completed==len)
{
$scope.labels=labels;
var pieOptions = 
{
segmentShowStroke : false,
animateScale : true
}
var expenses = document.getElementById("expenses").getContext("2d");
new Chart(expenses).Doughnut(piedata, pieOptions);
}
}
```

With same code in HTML it is working fine my data is

```
var pieData = [
    {
            label :"Value1",
            value : 0.598986,
            color :"#b5b8cf"
    },
    {
            label :"Value2",
            value : 0.41403,
            color : "#a3e1d4"
    },
    {
            label : "Value3",
            value : 2.163101,
            color : "#dedede"
    }
];
var pieOptions = {
    segmentShowStroke : false,
    animateScale : true
}
var expenses = document.getElementById("expenses").getContext("2d");
new Chart(expenses).Doughnut(pieData, pieOptions);
</script>
```

for this data inside HTML my chart is displaying the value

My html file is given below

```
<div class="ibox-title">
<h5>Value</h5>

</div>
<div class="ibox-content">
<div class="text-center">
<canvas id="expenses" height="140"></canvas>
</div>
labels : {{labels}}
</div>
```

I am getting printed on screen

> labels : ["Value1","Value2","Value3"]

I thinks that means my App is passing data to HTML but I am not getting it on charts

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It could very well be one of the annoying issues where your canvas is "0x0" when the chart gets rendered. To prove or disprove this, please wrap your `new Chart` in a setTimeout of ~1s and let me know if the problem still persists.

Comment: Hey @darryn.ten thanks for answer. How to do that please can you explain.

Comment: Chart is working when inside HTML but not working with Angular JS so how timeout will help me over here?

Comment: just to debug the issue, not as a fix...